# WPF MVVM C# - How do I bind a button's text to a LINQ expression and have it change dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, binding

I would like to bind button text to a LINQ expression, like this:

```cs
public string CloseButtonText => Roles.Any(r => r.IsChanged) ? "Save and close" : "Close";
```

...but it's not working. The text is properly set at startup, but it doesn't change when any of the RoleViewModel objects change.

This is how I've set it up.

```cs
public class RoleSelectionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RoleSelectionViewModel()
    {
        LoadRoles();
    }
    
    private readonly ObservableCollection<RoleViewModel> _roles = [];
    public IList<RoleViewModel> Roles => _roles;

    public string CloseButtonText => Roles.Any(r => r.IsChanged) ? "Save and close" : "Close";

    private void LoadRoles()
    {
        // Prevents crash when trying to read XML roles during design-time.
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new System.Windows.DependencyObject()))
        {
            return;
        }

        var roles = [ .. RolesManagement.ReadRolesXml().OrderBy(r => r.RoleName), ];
        roles.ForEach(r => Roles.Add(new RoleViewModel(r)));
    }
    // rest of the class...
```

```cs
public class RoleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RoleViewModel() { }

    public RoleViewModel(Role role) => Role = role;

    public Role Role { get; protected set; }

    public int RoleId => Role.RoleId;

    public string RoleName => Role.RoleName;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return Role.IssuedBy; }
        set
        {
            Role.IssuedBy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Department
    {
        get { return Role.Department; }
        set
        {
            Role.Department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return Role.Email; }
        set
        {
            Role.Email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // etc...
```

```cs
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isChanged = false;
    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get { return _isChanged; }
        set
        {
            _isChanged = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        if (propertyName != nameof(IsChanged))
        {
            IsChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Button
    x:Name="Close_Button"
    Width="96"
    Height="30"
    Padding="10,0,10,0"
    Background="#FF838383"
    Foreground="White"
    Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
    >
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="Close_Button_Text"
        Text="{Binding CloseButtonText}"
        />
</Button>
```

I also tried manually subscribing to the `RoleViewModel.PropertyChanged` event, but it didn't work either. Weirdly enough `Role_PropertyChanged` triggers when I click the close button, but not when any of the role properties change.

```cs
foreach (var role in Roles)
{
    role.PropertyChanged += Role_PropertyChanged;
}

private void Role_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(RoleViewModel.IsChanged))
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CloseButtonText));
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: I tried subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection`, but no dice. The `Role_PropertyChanged` method only triggers when I actually click the Close button; I've no idea why.

```cs
public string CloseButtonText { get; set; } = "Close";

private void LoadRoles()
{
    _roles.CollectionChanged += Roles_CollectionChanged;
    // rest of the method unchanged
}

private void Roles_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (RoleViewModel item in e.OldItems)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= Role_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (RoleViewModel item in e.NewItems)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += Role_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void Role_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is RoleViewModel role 
        && role.IsChanged 
        && e.PropertyName == nameof(RoleViewModel.IsChanged))
    {
        CloseButtonText = "Save and close";
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CloseButtonText));
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**: So as it turns out, you cannot bind to a LINQ expression like I originally intended. However, after adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on each `TextBox`'s binding, it worked. The default seems to be to raise the event after the `TextBox` loses focus. So the complete binding should look like this: `Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. I still had to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` and also subscribe to each `RoleViewModel`'s `PropertyChanged` event as described in the first edit though.

Comment: You don't.  LINQ expressions do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Whatever you bind the property to much implement that interface.  So you will need to write the code yourself.  Manually subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` handler should be the way to go.   Did you test it in the debugger?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. One of the ones I have used is to change the button text with Style.Triggers in my xaml based on a boolean value in my viewmodel that calls `OnPropertyChanged`. So, if `IsChanged` is true for your viewmodel, the trigger could rename to "Close"

Comment: You can listen to the collection's CollectionChanged event (or PropertyChanged and track the Count property) and compute the new text from the event handler.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I've tried debugging it. As I wrote at the end of my post, `Role_PropertyChanged` doesn't trigger until I actually click the Close button for some unknown reason.

Comment: @BionicCode I tried subscribing to the collection's `CollectionChanged` event and the `PropertyChanged` event on each RoleViewModel through that handler, but it didn't work. I added the new code to the bottom of my post.

Comment: The CloseButtonText property must raise the PropertyChanged event to trigger the Binding to update the target.

Comment: And you should filter the CollectionChanged action. Because you don't want to unsubscribe when items are moved. Also `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` (when `Clear()` is called) is not reflected by the `OldItems` property. I recommend to switch on the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction` object and add/removed handlers based on the switch case.

Comment: From an MVVM point of view it would be cleaner to bind the TextBlock to a e.g. `IsDirty` property (set when any of the `Role` items reported a change) and generate the actual label text using a converter. The view model should not be involved in UI logic. There shouldn't be a reason to modify the view model in order to modify UI element labels.

Comment: @BionicCode That does sound cleaner. I'll try that approach as well. However, I found out what the issue whas; I needed to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the TextBox binding to `PropertyChange` in order for the event to be raised immediately. The default seems to be `LostFocus`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, the default is LostFocus. But this is a TextBox issue and your question does not contain any TextBox. I assume that the user edits a TextBox which trigger the updating of a Role and that part wasn't working. But you still must let the ChangedButtonText property raise the PropertyChanged event (what is not happening in your posted code).  But I assume you are doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, **you cannot bind to a LINQ expression** like I originally intended. I changed the property to this: `public string CloseButtonText { get; set; } = "Close"`.

The problem I had was that the event was not being raised when I expected it to (when the text box content changed).
However, after adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on each `TextBox`'s binding, it worked. The default seems to be to raise the event after the `TextBox` loses focus. So the complete binding should look like this: `Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. I still had to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` and also subscribe to each `RoleViewModel`'s `PropertyChanged` event as described in the first edit though.